# Is it possible to install and encode whitewater videos (python) on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, video, encoding

I am hoping to use **whitewater** videos on my company's website however I am unable to install the software or encode videos on my windows PC, all of the documentation says to use a Mac.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whitewater

I have installed Python 3.6. And I installed the whitewater package using the command prompt:

`python whitewater\setup.py`

It appeared to install, but I can't encode any videos.

When I try to encode a video using the Command Prompt, I get the following error:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
>   Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
C:\Users\local-cluckett>python whitewater /test,mp4
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\local-cluckett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy
>   .py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)
>     File "C:\Users\local-cluckett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy
>   .py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)
>     File "whitewater__main__.py", line 5, in 
>       from .cli import main
>   SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
>
> C:\Users\local-cluckett>

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: have you tried `pip install whitewater`?

Comment: Hi @Alex thank you for getting back to me, the setup/install script ran, but I get errors whenever I try to encode a video, I've added some more detail to my question above

Comment: 1) `python whitewater /test,mp4` should be `python whitewater /test.mp4` in your example. 2) The library is for python 2.7 it seems.

Comment: Hi @AlexFung, you were correct about it requiring python 2.7. It appears to have installed correctly now. Unfortunately the program still doesn't work for me, despite putting in the correct commands. e.g. 'whitewater C:\whitewater\video.mp4' it returns the message 'video not found', however if I type in 'C:\whitewater\video.mp4' the video will open and begin to play so it is definitely the right path

Comment: For anyone else that may stumble upon this I also had to install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 to get it to install correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I had to install Python 2.7 from here - https://www.python.org/downloads/
(I had to use the standard 32 bit version despite using a 64 bit version of Windows 7, there is a really useful step by step guide here - https://www.howtogeek.com/197947/how-to-install-python-on-windows/):

I then had to install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from here - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

I could then install whitewater from PyPI by using the command prompt command:

**pip install whitewater**

Whitewater then appeared to install correctly, however whenever I tried to encode a video I got an error, e.g.

**whitewater C:\video.mp4**

**video not found**
**whitewater.whitewater.ProgramEnd**

I had to then install ffmpeg by downloading it from here - https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ and following this useful guide - http://adaptivesamples.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/

Finally it worked.